# How could I use binary log as relay log?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, binlog

I has a full backup of MySQL, and binary logs from the time of starting full backup.Can I restore the data in another instance use replication like only `start slave sql_thread;` rather than `mysql < mysql-binlog.xxxx`?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Do you have GTIDs enabled?

Answer (score 1):

If the Slave is at the state of the start of the binlogs, then simply perform a `CHANGE MASTER` to point the Slave at the start of the binlogs.  `POS` can be either 0 or 4.  (In case you see either of those.)

At that point, the Slave will rapidly "catch up".